# Is it possible to deploy workflow rules and field update actions which reference PersonAccount record types?

Tags: deployment, workflow, record-type, person-accounts, ant

I am performing a deployment from one sandbox to another using ant. The sandboxes both have `PersonAccount` functionality enabled. The source org has a `PersonAccount` record type with the name of `HCP` and in this source org there is a workflow rule and a field update action which sets the RecordType to `HCP` after create/update on the record based on the value of another field.

My problem is that the deployment to the target org fails with an error on the workflow action, that the `Account` object does not have a `RecordType` of `HCP` defined on it. This is semi-accurate as the `RecordType` is technically defined on the `PersonAccount` object and it does exist in the package.xml and the file source as noted below.

> Component Failures:
>   1. workflows/Account.workflow (Account.SetAccount_HCPRecordType) --
>   Error: In field: lookupValue - no RecordType named Account.HCP found

**PersonAccount.object**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <compactLayoutAssignment>SYSTEMPersonAccount</compactLayoutAssignment>
    <recordTypes>
        <fullName>HCP</fullName>
        <active>true</active>
```

My first attempt at a workaround was to pre-create the `HCP` record type manually in the target org on the Person Account and try the deployment again. This failed. Same error.

The only way that I was able to get a successful deployment of this package was to edit the `Account.object` file and remove the offending `<rules>` and `<fieldUpdates>` elements so that there was no reference in the package to the `HCP` record type on the `PersonAccount`.

1. Is this a bug or expected behavior?
2. What is the proper way to
   deploy workflow rules that are dependent on PersonAccount record
   types?

All files involved are SFDC API v.29

Comment: I've had the same problem and used the same workaround.

Comment: Mark, did you ever find another workaround? I'd think this would be an issue for anyone working with the non-profit starter pack. Might also be worth asking your question in their user group on Linked-in or their SF Chatter group.

Comment: The non-profit starter pack doesn't use person accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Maybe in the future, but don't count on it. #safeharbor